# How to loop over gif file finite number of times while creating mp4 as output with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am able to convert gif file to mp4 using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i animated.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" video.mp4
```

What I want to do is to loop over gif animation 3 times and convert to mp4.

I am able to do this with 2 shell commands. First one from above and then concatenate the same video 3 times.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '$PWD/video.mp4'\n%.0s" {1..3}) -c copy videoloop.mp4
```

I have also tried with -ignore_loop 0 option and setting time. It does work but it is not exactly what I am trying to do since I can extend the video but can not make exactly 3 loops.

```
ffmpeg -ignore_loop 0 -i animated.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -t 12 videoloop.mp4
```

So as you can see I am already able to achieve what I want, but with 2 shell commands:

```
ffmpeg -i animated.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" video.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '$PWD/video.mp4'\n%.0s" {1..3}) -c copy videoloop.mp4
```

Is it possible to do this with only one call to ffmpeg?

I tried with -loop option for the input file. It doesn't work for gifs. I also tried with -stream_loop. It creates something corrupted.

Comment: Which ffmpeg version do you have?

Comment: ffmpeg version 3.4.2-static

Comment: Upgrade to 4.0 and use `-stream_loop 2 -i animated.gif` - there was a bug with stream_loop fixed recently.

Comment: Thanks!
This is the final command that works with 4.0 version.
ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i animated.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" videoloop.mp4

Comment: Looks correct..

Answer (score 3):

I use to convert **gif** to **mp4** in two steps when dealing with LOOPING

e.g. GIF ---> LOOP ---> MP4

> **loop the gif itself first**. In this example, the output will be added by 2 repetitions
>
> [final file will play once, plus 2 repetitions (loops)]

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i normal.gif loop.gif
```

> **convert the LOOPED GIF to mp4**

```
ffmpeg -i loop.gif -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" loop.mp4
```

the parameters **-vf** was used to avoid the scale division error and to maintain the aspect ratio on fine, getting rid of the error message such as:

*height not divisible by 2 (320x569)*

*2 frames left in the queue on closing*

NOTE THAT: the **width** and the **height** was divided by 2 and then multiplied by 2 again

[ *quite tricky!* ] \o/